# Ajax Enabled Wcf Service cant find specific method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have strange behavior of Webservice.

Right now webservice looks like :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1
    {
        // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
        // To create an operation that returns XML,
        //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
        //     and include the following line in the operation body:
        //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
        [OperationContract]
        public string DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            return "Hello there";
        }

        // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
    }
```

And I can get Read from it in JS without problems:

```
   <script>




        function doWork() {
            Service1.DoWork(onSuccess, onFailure);
        }

        function onSuccess(result) {
            document.getElementById('txtValueContainer').value = result;
        }

        function onFailure(result) {
            window.alert(result);
        }


</script>
```

But, as soon as I am trying to send over something else then strings for example :

```
        [OperationContract]
        public Question[] OurServerOutput(string userid)
        {
            return Question.getQuestionsForUser(new Guid(userid)).ToArray();
        }

where 

        public static IEnumerable<Question> getQuestionsForUser( Guid userGuid)
        {
            LinqConnectionDataContext context = new LinqConnectionDataContext();
            var query = from c in context.Questions where c.UidUser == userGuid select c;
            return query;

        }
```

Javascript can't find my Service anylonger and I am getting an error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 132, column 13 in http://localhost/

0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Service1' is undefined
```

How do I send Array over Ajax Enabled WebService?

Comment: I removed the asp classic tag, this is an asp.net question.

Comment: Answer is quite simple: set Seriliazation on Linq DB to Unidirectional

Answer (score 0):

Answer was quite simple: set Seriliazation on Linq DB to Unidirectional